# ¿Cómo hacer para que las columnas saldos salgan null de las dos tablas si no coinciden o si no existen los datos y no repita la info?

Tags: sql, sql-server, server

```
select STOCK.CODIGO as CODIGO_ALMACEN,
       STOCK.LOTE AS LOTE_ALMACEN, 
       STOCK.SALDO AS SALDO_ALMACEN,
       CONTEO.CODIGO AS CONTEO_CODIGO,
       CONTEO.LOTE AS LOTE_CONTEO,
       CONTEO.SALDO AS CONTEOSALDO
from  (select B8_PRODUTO AS CODIGO ,
              B1_DESC AS DES, 
              LOTE.B8_LOTECTL AS LOTE,
              LOTE.B8_SALDO AS SALDO  
       from SB8010 AS LOTE 
       JOIN SB1010 AS PRODUCTO ON (LOTE.B8_PRODUTO = PRODUCTO.B1_COD)
       where LOTE.B8_FILIAL = '0105' 
       and LOTE.B8_LOCAL = '19' 
       AND LOTE.B8_SALDO > '0' 
       AND  B8_PRODUTO ='000002'
  ) STOCK
  
full join 

 (select B7_COD AS CODIGO, 
       B7_DESC2 AS DES ,
       B7_LOTECTL AS LOTE,
       B7_CONT1  AS SALDO 
 from UB7010
 WHERE B7_CONT1 > '0'AND B7_COD ='000002') CONTEO on CONTEO.CODIGO = STOCK.CODIGO
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ponemos ver que el conteo se repite y quiero que salga saldo null por que no deberia repetir o en todo caso que no muestre nada para esa fila por que ya se mostro arrriba...
y que sea viceversa por que tambien puede aparecer repetido a la izquierda repetido.

osea es un ejemplo de lo que tengo en almacen y lo que se conto en fisico...

tengo dos lotes en almacen pero en conteo solo tengo uno pero en este caso esta repitiendo por las dos filas del almacen...
Saludos
Gracias!

Comment: Bienvenido Juan Carlos Campos Giorgetti a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: ¿Que motor de base de datos usas? ¿versión?

Comment: Muchas gracias Patricio.
Si soy nuevo en esto ejej.
Sql server 2018 R2.
Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

En primer lugar, este tipo de solución, es mucho más adecuado hacerlo de la aplicación más que en la consulta, ya que terminamos complicando una consulta, talvez innecesariamente, para lograr algo que es muy simple de resolver desde la vista.

El problema básicamente se define como: mostrar el saldo una única vez, por cada `CODIGO_ALMACEN`, lo mostraríamos en la primer fila de cada grupo. La idea sería entonces, enumerar cada fila por cada `CODIGO_ALMACEN` con un orden que definamos y terminar mostrando el `SALDO` solo en la primer fila.

Vamos a usar dos herramientas que SQL Server ya contempla en tu versión

- La [**"common table expression"**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) que es una forma de definir una tabla temporal al vuelo, para usarla luego de forma más cómoda.
- La función para enumerar [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

La idea sería:

```
;WITH CTE AS ( 
select  STOCK.CODIGO as CODIGO_ALMACEN,
        STOCK.LOTE AS LOTE_ALMACEN, 
        STOCK.SALDO AS SALDO_ALMACEN,
        CONTEO.CODIGO AS CONTEO_CODIGO,
        CONTEO.LOTE AS LOTE_CONTEO,
        CONTEO.SALDO AS CONTEOSALDO,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY STOCK.CODIGO ORDER BY CONTEO.SALDO) AS RN
        from  (select   B8_PRODUTO AS CODIGO ,
                        B1_DESC AS DES, 
                        LOTE.B8_LOTECTL AS LOTE,
                        LOTE.B8_SALDO AS SALDO  
                        from SB8010 AS LOTE 
                        JOIN SB1010 AS PRODUCTO ON (LOTE.B8_PRODUTO = PRODUCTO.B1_COD)
                        where LOTE.B8_FILIAL = '0105' 
                        and LOTE.B8_LOCAL = '19' 
                        AND LOTE.B8_SALDO > '0' 
                        AND  B8_PRODUTO ='000002'
                    ) STOCK
        full join (
            select  B7_COD AS CODIGO, 
                    B7_DESC2 AS DES ,
                    B7_LOTECTL AS LOTE,
                    B7_CONT1  AS SALDO 
                from UB7010
                WHERE B7_CONT1 > '0'AND B7_COD ='000002'}
        ) CONTEO 
        on CONTEO.CODIGO = STOCK.CODIGO  
)
SELECT  CODIGO_ALMACEN
        LOTE_ALMACEN, 
        SALDO_ALMACEN,
        CONTEO_CODIGO,
        LOTE_CONTEO,
        (CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN CONTEOSALDO ELSE NULL END)
        FROM CTE
        ORDER BY CODIGO_ALMACEN, RN
```

Con `;WITH CTE AS (...)` generamos una tabla temporal dinámica y muy importante, materializamos la nueva columna del numerador, luego con `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY STOCK.CODIGO ORDER BY CONTEO.SALDO) AS RN`, numeramos cada fila, reiniciando el contador por cada `STOCK.CODIGO`, luego simplemente chequeamos la fila para mostrar el saldo únicamente en la primer fila.

Comment: Me parece muy buena idea todo..
Muchas Gracias...
Saludos!!!